# wordpress custom user capabilities and roles

Tags: wordpress

I am fairly new to wordpress and I am attempting to create custom capabilities and assign them to custom roles, however, I am stuck.

This is what I have but on calling the function within a plugin I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_cap()":

```
function setupCapabilities() {
    //create custom capabilities
    add_cap('view_all_holds');
    add_cap('view_advertiser_lockouts');
    add_cap('view_overages');
    add_cap('view_all_booked');
    add_cap('create_makegood_order');
    add_cap('edit_reports');

    //array for custom admin capabilities
    $adminCaps = array(
        'view_all_holds' => true, 
        'view_advertiser_lockouts' => true, 
        'view_overages' => true, 
        'view_all_booked' => true, 
        'create_makegood_order' => true, 
        'edit_reports' => true
    );

    //create new role with custom capabilities
    add_role('bam_admin', 'BAM Administrator', $adminCaps);

    //get user id
    $userID = get_current_user_id();

    //if the user id is me then add new role
    if ($userID == 46) { //me
        $user = new WP_User($userID);
        $user->add_role('bam_admin');
    }

    //check if the role was successfully applied
    if (in_array('bam_admin', (array) $userID->roles)) {
        echo 'You have succesfully created and checked a role.';
    } else {
        echo 'Something messed up';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

i will post my code i have for the same:

```
function add_capability()
{
    $role = get_role('players'); //user role

    $rolePerms = array('player_image','player_video'); //post types perms

    foreach($rolePerms as $rolePerm) { 

        $role->add_cap('publish_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('edit_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('delete_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('edit_published_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('delete_published_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('edit_others_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('delete_others_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('read_private_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('edit_private_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('delete_private_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm
        $role->add_cap('manage_categories_'.$rolePerm); // add ,false to remove the perm

    }

}
add_action('admin_init', 'add_capability');
```

so i had to add the perm to my post_type function

```
'capability_type'     => 'player_image'´
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following plugin for roles & capabilities.

[Click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/)